# Unable to send image file as part Datacontract

Tags: wcf, rest, service

I am developing a Wcf Restful Service which contains data contract "User" shown below

```
[DataContract]
public class User
{
    public User()
    {

    }
    [DataMember(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Mobile")]
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "IsImageUpdated")]
    public bool IsImageUpdated { get; set; }
}
```

Now i would like to add one mode data member of type Image,When i try to add Image with type Stream it showing exception

```
    [DataMember(Name = "Iamge")]
    public Stream Image { get; set; }
```

"The InnerException message was 'Type 'System.IO.FileStream' with data contract name 'FileStream:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.IO' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see InnerException for more details."

The service i am developing having many Data contract's,I read some posts which saying the issue can be resolved by changing the Datacontract to message contract,Does a service supports different contract types(like Data,Message).

i need a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible when using a WebHttpBinding.
Combining streamed and buffered Content is only possible when the binding has a SOAP message Format and you use MessageContract instead of DataContract.

Using a byte[] or returning the stream directly is supported.

```
[DataMember(Name = "Iamge")]
public byte[] Image { get; set; }
```

or

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Image")]
Stream GetImage();
```

or when using NetTcpBinding, WsHttpBinding, BasicHttpBinding, ...

```
[MessageContract]
public class ImageData
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public Stream Image { get; set; }
    [MessageHeader]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```